# Appending row with checkbox in google scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Im writing a small google script for an excel sheet which appends a row on a POST request: depending on the POST parameters I either append the row to the end, or I insert it in between rows.
One of the columns of the is actually a boolean that Im trying to represent as a checkbox.

The problem is when I try to append a row

`sheet.appendRow([e.parameter.parameter1, e.parameter.parameter2, "FALSE"]);`

It simply writes false in that column.

On the other hand when I insert a row in between other rows:

```
sheet.insertRows(position);
sheet.getRange("A" + (position)).setValue(e.parameter.parameter1);
sheet.getRange("B" + (position)).setValue(e.parameter.parameter2);
sheet.getRange("C" + (position)).setValue("FALSE");
```

The checkbox column (takes the format from the surrounding rows?) and becomes a checkbox.

[image: google sheet image]

Is there a simple solution to append a row with a column as a checkbox?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you appending to an Excel sheet or Google sheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You need to create a checkbox first with [data validation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder)

Sample:

```
 var checkbox = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireCheckbox().build();
 sheet.getRange("C" + (position)).setDataValidation(checkbox).setValue("FALSE");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding data to a new row using appendRow(), you can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77681345/13619825) at https://stackoverflow.com/a/77681345/13619825 for additional insights."

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35509408)