# Can I add multiple checkboxes in rows when a cell in each row contains a value?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Please help me out with this script that I found?

I'm not an experienced coder, so I'm just winging it at this point.

I want to simply make the process of adding check boxes to each new row automated with the following script:

```js
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); //change this to the name of your sheet
  ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  
  //PICK ONE & comment out the other one:
  var names = ss.getRange("Ranger");//Use this if you are naming the range (Refer Range)
  //var names = ss.getRange("B3:B");//Use this if you are naming the ranges
  
  var namesValues = names.getValues(); //Get array of all the names
  
  //PICK ONE & comment out the other one:
  var checkboxes = ss.getRange("Checkboxes"); //Use this if you are naming the range
  //var checkboxes = ss.getRange("C2:E2"); //Use this if you want to hard-code your range
  
  var cbRows = checkboxes.getHeight(); //Get # of rows in the ranges
  var cbValues = checkboxes.getValues(); //Get array of all the checkbox column cell values
  //Logger.log(cbValues);
  
  var newCBValues = new Array(cbRows); //Create an array to store all the new checkboxes values before we edit the actual spreadsheet
  
  for (var row = 0; row < cbRows; row++) {
    newCBValues[row] = new Array(0); // Make the array 2 dimensional (even though it only has 1 column, it must be 2D).
    if (namesValues[row] == "" || namesValues[row] == " ") { //If the name cell of this row is empty or blank then...
      newCBValues[row][0] = " "; //Set the value to one space (which will make the cell NOT true or false, and thus NOT display a checkbox).
      //Logger.log("newCBValues[" + row + "][0]: " + newCBValues[row][0]);
    }else{ //otherwise, if the name cell isn't blank...
      if (cbValues[row][0] === true) {
        newCBValues[row][0] = true; //Keep the checkbox checked if it's already checked
      }else{ //If the name cell isn't blank, and it's not true...
        newCBValues[row][0] = false; //Then Keep it or set it to False (an empty checkbox):
        
      }   
    }
  }
  checkboxes.setValues(newCBValues); // now that we have a completed array of our new checkbox values, let's edit the sheet with them!
  
}
```

I'm only able to add check boxes into one column, I would like to add check boxes into like 10 separate columns based on the value of 1 Row's cell values.[Spreadsheet I'm working on to capture data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOBiW.png)

Answer (score 0):

### You use `[row][0]` which refers to the 1st column of a range

If you want to perform an an action for all columns, you need to loop through those columns.

Sample:

```js
if (cbValues[row][0] == true) {
  for( var j = 0; j < newCBValues.length; j++){
    newCBValues[row][j] = true;
   }
}
```

Btw., see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58169178/11599789) how to build checkboxes instead of copying them.