# How to insert into the AppendRow checkbox Google app Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I create a form using Google Script's service. After entering all information from the form, it will be sent to Google Sheet. How to insert checkbox in appendRow? Doing it my way it just shows "DataValidationBuilder"

[image: Example Picture]

```js
function doPost(e) {
  
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  
  var destination_id = '1BBwRBt4dVvjRN9-qlxV-87oo5GJECOyM';  // ID OF GOOGLE DRIVE DIRECTORY;
  var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById(destination_id);
  
  var data = Utilities.base64Decode(e.parameter.fileData);
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(data, e.parameter.mimeType, e.parameter.fileName);
  destination.createFile(blob);
 

  listRecord(e.parameter.applicationDate,e.parameter.name,e.parameter.department,e.parameter.address, e.parameter.timeFrom, e.parameter.timeTo,e.parameter.cardmoney,e.parameter.persionalitycost,e.parameter.feecost,e.parameter.dailyAllowance, e.parameter.fileName, e.parameter.newCheckbox); 
  
  var htmlOutput =  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
  htmlOutput.message = 'File Uploaded';
  return htmlOutput.evaluate();                              
   

      
}

function listRecord(applicationDate, address,timeFrom,timeTo,cardmoney,persionalitycost, feecost,dailyAllowance )
{
    var newCheckbox = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation();
  newCheckbox.requireCheckbox()
  .setAllowInvalid(false)
  .build();
 
  var url = 'URL';  //URL OF GOOGLE SHEET;
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var recordsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("管理シート");
  recordsSheet.appendRow([setDataValidation(newCheckbox),new Date(),applicationDate,"name","department","work",address, timeFrom,timeTo , feecost,dailyAllowance,"","","","","","","","","","","",cardmoney,persionalitycost]);
  


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the data validation cannot be directly used with `appendRow`. So, in your situation, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
recordsSheet.appendRow([setDataValidation(newCheckbox),new Date(),applicationDate,"name","department","work",address, timeFrom,timeTo , feecost,dailyAllowance,"","","","","","","","","","","",cardmoney,persionalitycost]);
```

#### To:

```
recordsSheet.appendRow(["", new Date(), applicationDate, "name", "department", "work", address, timeFrom, timeTo, feecost, dailyAllowance, "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", cardmoney, persionalitycost]);
recordsSheet.getRange(recordsSheet.getLastRow(), 1).setDataValidation(newCheckbox);
```

#### Note:

- In your script, it seems that Web Apps is used. **In this case, when you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- You can see the detail of this in the report of "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

Comment: Hi, I have a part I hope you can advise me. I want to copy data based on checkbox ticked .I tried several ways but it didn't work. Can you help me?

Comment: **This is my code**
`function onEdit(e){
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName("main");
var sheet2=SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID').getSheetByName('Sheet2');
var cell=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName()=="main" && cell.getColumn()==1 && cell.getValue() == true){
 var row=cell.getRow();
 var range=sheet1.getRange(row,1,1,sheet1.getLastColumn());
 range.copyTo(sheet2.getRange((sheet2.getLastRow()+1),1)); }}`

Comment: @hiep Hoangduc Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But the issue of replying is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: @hiep Hoangduc Thank you for your response. When I saw your new question, I would like to check it.

Answer (score 0):

### Simpler way instead of 2 lines is:

> **Spreadsheet**

*If you have a simple sheet like the image below ↓*

[image]

*Hide the second row by right click the **2**, and click hide row(or the english word)*

[image: Hide row in sheet]

---

> **Google Script**

Then with the following code

```
yourSheet.appendrow(["Title-1","Name-1",true])
```

or

```
yourSheet.appendrow(["Title-2","Name-2", false])
```

---

*When I run the code*

[image: Example image of it working]